# Make a function call to functions inside jQuery closure

Tags: jquery, closures

When working with HTML and JavaScript I just simply call to a function from my `<a>` tag using

```
<a href="#" onclick="helloWorld()">Hello World</a>
```

I also want to make an AJAX call so using jQuery is quite easier, but I also want to wait until the DOM finishes loading so I declare my function inside the jQuery closure.

```
<a href="#" onclick="helloWorld()">Hello World</a>
<br>
<a href="#" onclick="ajaxCall()">Make AJAX Call</a>

<script>
    function helloWorld() {
        alert('Hello World');
    }

    $(function() {
        function ajaxCall() {
            alert('AJAX Call');
        }
    });
</script>
```

The first link is working, but the second is not, how should I fix it?
Please advise.
Thanks.

**Edited**

jQuery event attachment is working fine, but `<a onclick="functionName()">` would offer less coding (if it can be working)

So sorry I forgot to mention about I'm not looking for jQuery event attachment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `$(function() {. Because it uses when you are using jQuery.

```
<script>
        function helloWorld() {
            alert('Hello World');
        }

            function ajaxCall() {
                alert('AJAX Call');
            }
    </script>

    <a href="#" onclick="helloWorld()">Hello World</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#" onclick="ajaxCall()">Make AJAX Call</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using it in ready?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // function declaration:
  function ajaxCall() {
    alert('AJAX Call');
  }

  // call the function using delegation because you use ajax call
  $( document ).on( 'click','#ajax',ajaxCall );
});
```